# How to do isolated transaction in Postgres with Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I am using Slick to access my Postgres SQL database.

I need to do a transaction that is isolated (serializable or repeatable read).

I found the following code online here https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/218

```
  def withIsolatedTransaction[R](level: Int)(block: => R)(implicit session: Session) = {
    require(session.conn.getAutoCommit, "A transaction has already been started")
    val oldLevel = session.conn.getTransactionIsolation
    session.conn.setTransactionIsolation(level)
    val r = session.withTransaction(block)
    session.conn.setTransactionIsolation(oldLevel)
    r
  }
```

Could someone tell me if this is good idea to use in my code, or if there is a better way to do transaction isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what you're looking for? http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/connection.html#transactions

(btw the code you referenced has an open pull request on slick (milestone 2.1) here: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/218 )

Comment: I think I'm stuck with slick 1.0, unless play-slick plugin supports slick 2.0

Comment: I think the code you now have is the way to go for the moment. Also see this blog article about isolation w play and also slick: http://blog.codacy.com/understanding-isolation-levels/